# Hibernate JUnit can't find hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, junit

script gives error when using JUnit to buildSessionFactory. I also tried using:

```
 return new Configuration().configure("src/test/resources/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

I've been moving it around but every time I run it. The test method can't find hibernate.cfg.xml.

In particular I am using Maven2 as well.

Error:

```
SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: src/test/resources/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

My project/workspace name is also "test" so I tried "test/src/test" too. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct form is:

```
return new Configuration().configure("/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

`configure(String)` method looks for classpath resource and everything under `/src/test/resources/` is available on the classpath in Maven when you run your tests.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think it's because JUnit context is different from the context that hibernate is looking for the file.

Comment: That's strange. I just tried creating a simple Maven project with single unit test where I call the configuration and the hibernate.cfg.xml file was successfully found. Could you share some more details (perhaps the unit test code or how you run it)?

Comment: Another solution which works for me is passing `File` instance with path relative to your project root to the `configure` method (`new File("src/test/resources/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml")`). Could you try if it works for you?

Comment: I'm not sure what I did but I moved it into Meta-inf like before, and then removed the first "/" in META-INF and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

Delete "src" and try again to run.

```
return new Configuration().configure("/test/resources/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Deleting src just deletes everything, doesn't make sense.